# Load template in tab content

Tags: magento-1.9

I add a tab like this:

```
$this->addTab('subcategorie_volgorde', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Subcategorie volgorde'),
            'content'   => "<h2>Hello world</h2>",
        ));
```

I have tried this, but I don't really understand how it works:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('yourmodule/yourblock')->toHtml()
```